# How to Verify OTP with on Same page in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a page where i want once the user click on verify email the user get and email with otp and there is also an input field from where the user is going to enter the OTP and we can  Verify Here what i did when user click on verify email he a ajax request send on the server by which a mail is send to user and then in response server is sending back the opt to client as well which i then store in a variable in the localstorage of javascript But i feel it is not safe a lot Any better way to that

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to save the OTP at all. Once the user enters the OTP and presses verify, you send the OTP to the server in an AJAX call, and then your server can perform the verification on the backend.

Comment: I want to do verification on frontend it is easier

Comment: Doing it on the frontend is actually harder and less secure. Verification of sensitive info should always be done on the backend